# How do I achieve this following function only using while loop?

Tags: python-3.x

I'm currently working on this problem that ask me to generate an arrow pattern using loops function that looks something like this:

```
"How many columns? 3"

*
 *
  *
 *
*
```

I know I can do this with for loop(probably more efficient too), but that is not what I aimed for. I wanted to achieve this only using while loop.

I have some ideas: 
1. I set up a control variable and an accumulator to control the loop
2. I then write 2 separate loops to generate the upper and lower part of the pattern. I was thinking about inserting the space before the asterisks using method like this:
(accumulator - (accumulator - integer)) * spaces.

```py
#Ask the user how many column and direction of column
#they want to generate
Keep_going = True
Go = 0
while keep_going:
   Column_num = int(input("How many columns? "))
   if Column_num <= 0:
       print("Invalid entry, try again!")
   else: 
       print()
       Go = 1

#Upper part
while Keep_going == True and Go == 1:
   print("*")
   print(""*(Column_num - (Column_num - 1) + "*")
```

...but I soon realized it wouldn't work because I don't know the user input and thus cannot manually calculate how many spaces to insert before asterisks. Now everything on the internet tells me to use for loop and range function, I could do that, but I think that is not helpful for me to learn python since I couldn't utilize loops very well yet and brute force it with some other method just not going to improve my skills.

I assume this is achievable only using while loop.

Comment: You can mimic a for loop with a while loop by using a counter and increasing (or decreasing) it during every iteration of the while loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
#Take your input in MyNumber
MyNumber = 5
i = 1
MyText = '\t*'
while i <=MyNumber:
  print(MyText.expandtabs(i-1))
  i = i+1
i = i-1
while i >=1:
  print(MyText.expandtabs(i-1))
  i = i-1
```

[Python - While Loop](https://alphacodingskills.com/python/python-while-loop.php)

Comment: I will try to set up two vars to control two different loops, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well first you have to understand that a while loop loops until a requirement is met.
And looking at your situation, to determine the number of spaces before the * you should have an ongoing counter, a variable that counts how many spaces are needed before you continue.  For example:

```
###Getting the number of columns###
while True:
    number=int(input('Enter number of rows: '))
    if number<=0:
        print('Invalid')
    else:
        ###Ending the loop###
        break

#This will determine the number of spaces before a '*'
counter=0

#Loops until counter equals number
while counter!=number:
    print(" "*counter + "*")
    #Each time it loops the counter variable increases by 1
    counter=counter+1

counter=counter-1

#Getting the second half of the arrow done
while counter!=0:
    counter=counter-1
    print(" "*counter + "*")
```

Please reply if this did not help you so that i can give a more detailed response